# Get information about current logged in user?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a flask application in which there are three permissions of a user model. I want to use data about the current user who is logged in in order to restrict or grant access to certain pages. I'm unsure how to load the data about the current user in session into a variable to get the permission level from the actual user who is logged in. Any suggestions? I was thinking I could use g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you look at using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which provides user session management for Flask. You can then extend your User model to store whatever extra information you need and Flask-Login provides you a proxy object in the form of `current_user` that is accessible from your request handlers and templates.